# Please what is Unknown ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've had this same error for 3 nights in a row. I create a component(Navbar.vue) and import it into App.vue then run npm run dev" and the screen goes white. I check the console and it's always Unknown ReferenceError: Navbar is not defined. The past two nights I've deleted the whole component and done it from beginning but when I import it, it works fine. This night I'm trying to use firebase with my project and it cant find the InitializeApp function. I'm so confused and frustrated please help

Comment: You need to add your code here. Otherwise how can we tell what is wrong? Show us your `Navbar.vue` and the component where you `import` the `NavBar` at the least.

Comment: did you also register the component or did you only import it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported it first with:

```
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
```

and then registered:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Navbar
  }
}
```